# Solr: how to manage irrelevant results when not sorting by relevance?

Tags: search, solr

Case in point: say we have a search query that returns 2000 results ranging from very relevant to hardly relevant at all. When this is sorted by relevance this is fine, as the most relevant results are listed on the first page.

However, when sorting by another field (e.g. user rating) the results on the first page are full of hardly-relevant results, which is a problem for our client. Somehow we need to only show the 'relevant' results with highest ratings.

I can only think of a few solutions, all of which have problems:

1 - Filter out listings on Solr side if relevancy score is under a threshold. I'm not sure how to do this, and from what I've read this isn't a good idea anyway. e.g. If a result returns only 10 listings I would want to display them all instead of filter any out. It seems impossible to determine a threshold that would work across the board. If anyone can show me otherwise please show me how!

2 - Filter out listings on the application side based on score. This I can do without a problem, except that now I can't implement pagination, because I have no way to determine the total number of filtered results without returning the whole set, which would affect performance/bandwidth etc... Also has same problems of the first point.

3 - Create a sort of 'combined' sort that aggregates a score between relevancy and user rating, which the results will then be sorted on. Firstly I'm not sure if this is even possible, and secondly it would be weird for the user if the results aren't actually listed in order of rating.

How has this been solved before? I'm open to any ideas!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If they're not relevant, they should be excluded from the result set. Since you want to order by a dedicated field (i.e. user rating), you'll have to tweak how you decide which documents to include in the result at all.

In any case you'll have to define "what is relevant enough", since scores aren't really comparable between queries and doesn't say anything about "this was xyz relevant!".

You'll have to decide why those documents that are included aren't relevant and exclude them based on that criteria, and then either use the review score as a way to boost them further up (if you want the search to appear organic / by relevance). Otherwise you can just exclude them and sort by user score. But remember that user score, as an experience for the user, is usually a [harder problem to make relevant than just order by the average of the votes](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36265.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Usually the client can choose different ordering options, by relevance or ratings for example. But you are right that ordering by rating is probably not useful enough. What you could do is take into account the rating in the relevance scoring. For example, by multiplying an "organic" score with a rating transformed as a small boost. In Solr you could do this with `Function Queries`. It is not hard science, and some magic is involved. Much is common sense. And it requires some very good evaluation and testing to see what works best.

Alternatively, if you do not want to treat it as a retrieval problem, you can apply faceting and let users do filtering of the results by rating. Let users help themselves. But I can imagine this does not work in all domains.

Engineers can define what relevancy is. Content similarity scoring is not only what constitutes relevancy. Many Information Retrieval researchers and engineers agree that contextual information should be used besides only the content similarity. This opens a plethora of possibilities to define a retrieval model. For example, what has become popular are *Learning to Rank* (LTR) approaches where different features are learnt from search logs to deliver more relevant documents to users given their user profiles and prior search behavior. Solr offers this as [module](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Learning+To+Rank).